# Where do I connect the green wire on my dishwasher?

Tags: wiring

I'm installing a new dishwasher and the dishwasher itself has the black, white and green wire, the power supply  (which is coming out of the floor of the house) doesn't have a green wire it has a black wire and white wire. What do I do with the green wire that is coming from the dishwasher junction box?[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the power supply wires please?

Comment: The green wire goes to ground and I'm sure that it's a required connection for a dishwasher installation.  I'm surprised that your old one didn't have it.  Find out where the other wires, which are coming out of the floor are coming from locate the green wire.  If there isn't one, you should run a new wire from the panel.

Comment: Is the box metal with metal conduit to the box?

Comment: Yes the box is metal with flexible medal conduit running to dishwasher.

Comment: The dishwasher has a junction box with a 1/2" knockout hole built into it, right?  Also, how long is that flex conduit whip?

Comment: Yes it does have a junction box.  the flex conduit is 48" long.

Answer (score 1):

### The flex is your grounding path, so cap off the green wire

In your situation, the metal conduit (flex, then rigid/EMT) is serving as the equipment grounding path, via the conduit fitting going into a 1/2" knockout (KO) on the dishwasher junction box, so you don't have a ground wire coming in.  This means you can simply cap the green ground wire off; if that's not satisfactory for some reason, you can use a *grounding locknut* instead of the existing locknut on the fitting, then attach the green wire to the screw on the grounding locknut.